How do I clear my react state variable within useeffect?
How can I accomplish this?
const [data, setData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
   setData([]); // Clear the data
   fetchData();
}, []);

I want all data to be cleared on initial page load and then fetch some new data. I can't await the usestate setter

You would already be setting the state's initial value when you create the state (useState([])) you shouldn't need to set it again.

@DBS The problem is that react rerenders multiple times during strict rendering, so my fetchData function is just concatenating duplicate data

The problem is you empty dependency array. useEffect only runs when a dependency is changed and since [] never changes it only runs once.
To reset ever render you can change your useEffect to:
const [data, setData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
   if(data) {
     setData([]);
  }
   fetchData();
}, [data]);


How do I know that setData([]) clears before fetchData runs?

You would probably want conditional call fetchData() when you need the data.

Not sure what you mean. I need it on page load

If you need it on page load this should work fine.  Are you experiencing any problems with it?

. I haven't tried it yet because I don't think it will work because of that problem of setData not running before fetchData does
